# MVC 4 Web API Template - what can be deleted

Tags: visual-studio, templates, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Using VS2010, creating a new MVC 4 Web API project. Just wondering, can the .js-files in the Script folder be deleted, or are they somehow related to the magic beneath? How about those cshtml- files in the Views folder, I can't see that they are necessary for a REST-service, or again, are they part of the underlying technology. My guess, it can all be deleted safely - but just to be sure...

Bonus question (while I'm here): recommendations for unit- and integrationtesting REST-services, got any?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your project **only** exposes a series of WebAPI controllers then that implies that your project will never serve actual HTML-based content. Thus, you can safely delete all files related to that content, such as:

- HTML files (.cshtml)
- JavaScript files (.js)
- CSS style sheets (.css)
- Images (.jpg, .png, .gif)